# Linux - Scp, download directory from server to local, using ssh

Tags: linux, scp

I am trying to download a directory from my cloud server to my local, using `scp`, with the following:

```
scp -i ./.ssh/mykey.pem -r -p admin@11.11.251.205:/var/lib/mongodb 127.0.0.1:/var/lib/mongod
```

`admin` is of course the remote, for which I need to key, while 127.0.0.1 is the local.

I receive however the error message:

```
Host key verification failed.
lost connection
```

If I try to connect through ssh to my server using `ssh -i ./.ssh/mykey.pem admin@11.11.251.205` it does work.

Could anyone point me to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For copying to the local server, you don't need the `127.0.0.1:`. Just this will do:

```
scp -i ./.ssh/mykey.pem -r -p admin@11.11.251.205:/var/lib/mongodb /var/lib/mongod
```

With the `127.0.0.1:`, scp makes another SSH connection to the server at 127.0.0.1 and acts as if it was copying between two remotes. The SSH server at 127.0.0.1 might be failing host key verification.

Answer (score 1):

From Man page,

> scp [-346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file] [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program] [[`user@]host1`:]file1 ... [[`user@]host2`:]file2

So when you are using `127.0.0.1` at last portion, `scp` recognized that as `host2`. So then `scp` will try to logged in at `127.0.0.1` host with current `username`, based on the identity file (`./.ssh/mykey.pem`) and returns error, may be because there is no information about `host2`. So just following will work fine,

```
$scp -i ./.ssh/mykey.pem -r -p admin@11.11.251.205:/var/lib/mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
```

OR

```
$cd /var/lib/mongodb
$scp -i ./.ssh/mykey.pem -r -p admin@11.11.251.205:/var/lib/mongodb .
```